# How to route CRUD operations in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code for node.js, express, and a MongoDB connection using mongoose.

Firstly I try on a single file named server.js and it's working without express. But now I want to do it in express but it's not working.

It's just simple program that read and create sample `Bear` objects in mongo database.

Here it is my **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

//var Bear = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

router.use(function(req,res,next){
  console.log('something is happening');
  next();
});

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});

// more routes for our API will happen here




// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /api

app.use('/', router);
app.use('/bears', users);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

and here it is my **users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear',BearSchema);


router.route('/bears')

    // create a bear (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var bear = new Bear();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
        bear.name = req.body.name;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)

        // save the bear and check for errors
        bear.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
        });

    });
module.exports = router;
```

Please tell me how to route the CRUD operations.

Comment: Please specify what error you are facing. Please comment the error here? So I can debug it.

Answer (score 2):

You cant have two module.exports in one file. The one, which is at the bottom of file rewrites all others.

You need two files, something like

controllers/users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/bears')

    // create a bear (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var bear = new Bear();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
        bear.name = req.body.name;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)

        // save the bear and check for errors
        bear.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
        });

    });
module.exports = router;
```

models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear',BearSchema);
```

In your app.js, you can do this :

```
var user = require('controllers/user');
app.use('/users', user);
```

It endpoint now listen at `/users/bears`

If you need your model somewhere, just load it with

```
var userModel = mongoose.model('User');
```

---

I would recommend to download and run this [template](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose/wiki), it is more easily to add new features, when you see, how they are already implemented

Answer (score 0):

[CRUD operation nodejs expressjs mongodb mongoose - Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejatq3rHOiI&list=PLEYOHK_Twag7GLOUAaEHYzf5i9_AiucR-&index=3&t=0s,"tutorial")

**models/emp.js**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var conn = mongoose.Collection;
var empSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    age: String,
    gender: String
});

var empModel = mongoose.model('Emp', empSchema);
module.exports = empModel;
```

**routes/index.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var empModel = require('../models/emp');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/employee", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  empModel.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', result:docs });
  })
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
 const emp = new empModel({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    age: req.body.age,
    gender: req.body.gender
    });
emp
.save()
.then(result => {
  res.redirect("/");
})
.catch(err => {
res.status(500).json({ error: err });
});
});

router.get('/update', function(req, res, next) {
  empModel.find({},function(err, docs) {
    res.render('update', { title: 'Express', result: docs });
  })
});

router.post('/update', function(req, res, next) {
empModel.findOneAndUpdate({ email: req.body.email },{ $set: { name: req.body.name, age: req.body.age, gender:req.body.gender } },{ returnOriginal: false }).exec().then(result => {
res.redirect("/");
 }).catch(err => {
  res.status(500).json({ error:err });
 });
});

router.get('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
  empModel.find({},function(err, docs) {
    res.render('delete', { title: 'Express', result: docs });
  })
});

router.post('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
  empModel.remove({ email: req.body.email }).exec().then(result => {
    res.redirect("/");
   }).catch(err => {
  res.status(500).json({ error:err });
 });
});
module.exports = router;
```

**views/index.js**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title><%= title %></title>
        <style>
        .login-form {
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        }
        .login-form h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #4d4d4d;
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
        }
        .login-form input[type="password"],
        .login-form input[type="text"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        .login-form input[type="submit"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            background-color:red;
            border: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        </style>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="sotre">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  -->
</head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <%= title %>
    </a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
    </nav>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table  table-condensed" width="100%"  >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Sr</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <% if(result.length){ 
                    for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) { %>
                        <tr>
                        <td><%=i+1%></td>

                         <td><%=result[i].name%></td>
                             <td><%=result[i].email%></td>
                        <td><%=result[i].age%></td>
                        <td><%=result[i].gender%></td>

                </tr>   <%}}%>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="login-form">
            <h1>CRUD OPERATION</h1>
                 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/">Insert</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/update">Update</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/delete">Delete</a></li>
                 </ul>
            <form action="/" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age" required>
                <input type="text" name="gender" placeholder="Gender" required>
                <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>

        </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using GET requests to change state is a bad practice.